# Flatness and m-adic completions.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, and $M$ be an arbitary a module. It is well known, that $M$ is flat iff every localization by maximal ideals of $M$ is flat. Is it also true, if we consider  m-adic completions instead of localizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, if $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, then the completion of $M$ at every maximal ideal is trivial (since $M$ is divisible), but $M$ is not flat.

Comment: And what if we consider not maximal, but prime completions?

Comment: Well then it's certainly true (but utterly useless) if $A$ is a domain.  I don't know about the general case